# Dynamic values with in json file upload - jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to POST JSON data using HTTP POST sampler in Jmeter. My data has few values which need to be passed based on results from previous samplers. Below is the sample data and I need is, last name and date from a previous GET Response.

```
{"people":{"primaryPerson":{"id":"1234","date":"2018-02-13",firstName":"Mr","lastName":"apple-eye","birthday":"1980-1-1","gender":"MALE","personType":"PRIMARY"}}
```

I have json extractors in the previous sampler to extract all 3 values but I don't know how to use them with body data upload. I am using 
`{__FileToString(${__eval(${fileName})},,)}` to upload the above data.

In short, I need to know how I can replace `ID, LASTNAME and DATE` using the previous sampler extracted data when I am passing data in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Amend your file to look like:

   ```
   {
     "people": {
       "primaryPerson": {
         "id": "${foo}",
         "date": "${bar}",
         "firstName": "Mr",
         "lastName": "${baz}",
         "birthday": "1980-1-1",
         "gender": "MALE",
         "personType": "PRIMARY"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Amend your [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) functions combination to look like

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(request.json,,)})}
   ```
3. Replace `foo`, `bar`, `baz` with actual JMeter Variables Reference Names and `request.json` with relative or full path to your JSON file (modified as per point one)

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri Tyour solution has solved my issue of passing dynamic values. Now i am stuck with another issue. When i post data using:  ${__eval(${__FileToString(C:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/create_client_data.txt,,)})}, i see that POST data has two forward slashes before it starts,  like below POST data://{
  "people": {
    "primaryPerson": {
      "id": "1234",
      "date": "2018-01-14}",
      "firstName": "Mr",
      "lastName": "apple-eye",
      "birthday": "1980-1-1",
      "gender": "MALE",
      "personType": "PRIMARY"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I solved the issue by adding a HTTP Header Manager with Content Type and Accept Encoding parameters. Thanks again for the above solution.